# Different between verb + ing and verb + ed

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

Can somebody helps to explain what are the differences between these sentences? 
What grammar is this?

```
ex)

1.  
   - This is an added product
   - This is an adding product
   - This is an additional product

2. 
   - I saw an arrested person 
   - I saw an arresting person
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. - This is an added product: This is a product that has been added to... The product was the object of an action (adding). [participial adjective from passive/past/perfect participle]
   - This is an adding product: This is a product that is adding somenthing to... The product is the acting subject. [participial adjective from present/active participle]
   - This is an additional product: This is a product that comes as an addition to... The product is declared as an addition to something. [adjective]
2. - I saw an arrested person: I saw a person, which was arrested (by someone). The person was the object of an action (arresting). [participial adjective from passive/past/perfect participle]
   - I saw an arresting person: I saw a person, which was arresting (another person). The person is the acting subject. [participial adjective from present/active participle]